# undefined is not an object firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential

Tags: javascript, facebook, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

Here is my code.. its pretty simple.. just trying to allow a user to authenticate through facebook and then add it to the Firebase system!
I should mention that I am using React Native, I did read that various parts of the Firebase library does not work with React Native.

```
const auth = firebase.auth();
const provider = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider;

LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile'])
.then(loginResult => {

    alert("login results")
    if (loginResult.isCancelled) {
        alert('user canceled');
        return;
    }
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
    .then(accessTokenData => {
        const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(accessTokenData.accessToken);
        alert("Credential: " + credential )
        return auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    })
    .then(credData => {
        console.log(credData);
        alert("CRED data:::" + credData)
        alert(firebase)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        alert("ERROR:::" + err)
        alert(firebase)

    });
});
```

The only reasoning I can really think of for this is that Firebase is undefined or it does not finish initializing.. although it seems to be.. maybe I can put in some sort of promise to ensure it has initialized.
(Any ideas on how to do that?)

Although firebase seems to be initalized.. but I went through the api reference and can't really find any reason why .auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential would not exist

Any help would be great!

Comment: Exactly which error is shown in console?

Comment: replace firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(..)
  with provider.credential(..)

Comment: Upgrade to the latest 3.3.0 version. There was a problem in the type definitions in the previous version.

Comment: @bojeil upgraded it to 3.3.0.. I just did "npm install firebase --save" and restarted the simulator. Hopefully that was the complete process... didn't seem to work.. got the exact same error

Comment: @Bommox did that, now the error is "Type Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'provider.credential')

Comment: the only thing I can really think of now is that this code is simply executing before my firebase code.. otherwise it does not really make sense..i am using firebase version 3.3.0

Answer (score 9):

I was having this exact same issue, and I have a solution that worked for me, but I'm not sure if it will be the same for you.

I was instantiating my firebase class through a separate module, in a file called **FirebaseService.js**

```
'use-strict';

const firebase = require('firebase');
const APP_BASE = 'https://your-unique-url.firebaseapp.com/'

const FIREBASE_CONFIG = {
    apiKey: '[super_unique]',
    authDomain: 'your-unique-url.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: APP_BASE,
    storageBucket: 'your-unique-url.appspot.com',
};

export const Firebase = firebase.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG);
```

I was then using it everywhere else in my code by importing it:

```
const { Firebase } = require ('./services/FirebaseService');
```

This appeared to be fine until I got around to implementing facebook login, and that's when I started having the same issue.

I had to import firebase in the screen that was trying to login with facebook. instead of requiring my own service, I used the npm module:

```
const firebase = require('firebase');
```

After that, I was able to access FacebookAuthProvider.credential. I'm really not sure why this is the case, there may have been something wrong with my use of modules

Comment: Had the same exact issue using the same exact process. Strange... Glad I came across this post! Thanks!

Comment: It's 2020 and your answer still works. Fascinating!

Comment: This was the issue for me too. Instead of FirebaseService.js, I just initialized Firebase in App.js and imported the npm module anywhere I needed it.