# React Native, does firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider not work

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

Just trying to get Facebook Auth working on my React Native app.. running version 3.3 of the Firebase api...

Whenever I try to call `firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider` it says that it is undefined. I know most of firebase is working as I am able to make pushs and pulls from the database.

```
const provider = firebaseObj.auth.FacebookAuthProvider;
```

Any ideas? was this not added to the React Native library? or am I just doing something wrong? If so is there any other solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/k3W5ezNoCP4

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39204923/undefined-is-not-an-object-firebase-auth-facebookauthprovider-credential/39340963#39340963